# react redirect issue I'm getting cannot read setState of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to redirect to the second page on button click. Yet, Im getting cannot read setState of undefined when working the code below.

```
  this.state = {
  arr: [],
  redirect: false
};
setRedirect() {
   this.setState({
  redirect : true
})
}


renderRedirect(){
  if (this.state.redirect) {
  return <Redirect to='/target' />
 }
}

render() {
return (
    <div>
    {this.renderRedirect()}
    <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
   </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add setState inside constructor or define as class property**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    arr: [],
    redirect: false
  }
}
```

**Or**

```
class abc extends Component {
  state = {
    arr: [],
    redirect: false,
  }
}
```

**Also**

Change function to es6 or use bind

*ES6 Solution*

```
setRedirect = () => {
   // Code block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the setDirect function like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
  arr: [],
  redirect: false
 };
 setRedirect() {
  this.setState({
   redirect: true
  })
 }


 renderRedirect(){
  if (this.state.redirect) {
   return <Redirect to='/target'/>
  }
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    {this.renderRedirect()}
    <button onClick={this.setRedirect.bind(this)}>Redirect</button> //binding here is important
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

or you have to use the constructor of class

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  arr: [],
  redirect: false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Constructor**

```
this.state = {
  arr: [],
  redirect: false
}
```

function that toggle redirect flag outside **constructor**

```
setRedirect=()=>{
  this.setState({redirect:true})
}
```

finally you render method

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>
      {this.renderRedirect()}
      <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
     </div>
  )
}
```

I think here is issue of binding `this` if you haven't written setState in `constructor`. If so then
there are threee ways of `changes this` so that you `setRedirect` can have access to this of whole class. (so that it can access `state`).

1. binding in render like onClick={()=>this.setRedirect.bind(this)}
2. binding in constructor like

   `this.setRedirect = this.setRedirect.bind(this)`
3. last on considering performance the above menthod `setRedirect =()=>{}`

Because 1,2 creates new function at every render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move state inside constructor and bind setRedirect in constructor only.

Few Other answers suggested to bind it directly in render don’t do that. Bind it always in constructor

To fix the issue primarily you need to bind setRedirect function

```
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             arr: [],
             redirect: false
         };
         this.setRedirect = this.setRedirect.bind(this);
     }
```

Also Change

```
    <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
```

To

```
    <button onClick={() => this.setRedirect()}>Redirect</button>
```

Otherwise setRedirect gets called on render so to prevent that use () =>